# C# Adding images to a list

Tags: c#, image, list

I'm trying to add images already used to an imageList named "Images1".
I'm not really good in coding programs but I know that the rest of my program is working except the fact that "Images1" does not exist for the two last voids. I searched to resolve this problem but I have difficulty to find an answer for this specific case.

How can I make my image list "Images1" available for all my private voids?

This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Resources;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Booster_pack_2
{
    public partial class Form3 : Form
    {
        public Form3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<Image> Images1 = new List<Image>();
            ResourceManager rm = Booster_pack_2.Properties.Resources.ResourceManager;
           string index1 = textBox1.Text;
            Bitmap image1 = (Bitmap)rm.GetObject(index1);
            pictureBox1.Image = image1;
            Images1.Add((Image)Booster_pack_2.Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(index1));
        }
        private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ResourceManager rm = Booster_pack_2.Properties.Resources.ResourceManager;
            string index2 = textBox2.Text;
            Bitmap image2 = (Bitmap)rm.GetObject(index2);
            pictureBox2.Image = image2;
            Images1.Add((Image)Booster_pack_2.Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(index2));
        }
        private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ResourceManager rm = Booster_pack_2.Properties.Resources.ResourceManager;
            string index3 = textBox3.Text;
            Bitmap image3 = (Bitmap)rm.GetObject(index3);
            pictureBox3.Image = image3;
            Images1.Add((Image)Booster_pack_2.Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(index3));
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Declare `List<Image> Images1` as a member of your class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put it in the proper scope. If you need to access it in all your event handlers, make it a class member:

```
namespace Booster_pack_2
{
public partial class Form3 : Form
{
    List<Image> Images1;
    public Form3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Images1 = new List<Image>();
        ResourceManager rm = Booster_pack_2.Properties.Resources.ResourceManager;
       string index1 = textBox1.Text;
        Bitmap image1 = (Bitmap)rm.GetObject(index1);
        pictureBox1.Image = image1;
        Images1.Add((Image)Booster_pack_2.Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(index1));
    }
    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ResourceManager rm = Booster_pack_2.Properties.Resources.ResourceManager;
        string index2 = textBox2.Text;
        Bitmap image2 = (Bitmap)rm.GetObject(index2);
        pictureBox2.Image = image2;
        Images1.Add((Image)Booster_pack_2.Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(index2));
    }
    private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ResourceManager rm = Booster_pack_2.Properties.Resources.ResourceManager;
        string index3 = textBox3.Text;
        Bitmap image3 = (Bitmap)rm.GetObject(index3);
        pictureBox3.Image = image3;
        Images1.Add((Image)Booster_pack_2.Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(index3));
    }
```

}
}

I'd advise moving this line: Images1 = new List();
to the constructor instead, just in case textBox1 isn't edited first.